# samba net usershare returned 255 error

Tags: samba

I just did a update to my system, one of which was Samba for UBUNTU 10.04 and now it will not allow me to get privilages when I use Nautilus.

Any ideas on how I can get this back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a permission problem described here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/31818

Quick fix:

```
chown root:sambashare /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

Regards